# How to do multiple checks for a value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is  my table

[image]

Assumptions:

..If the last entry of valid for an ID is 1 then its good

..If the last entry of valid for an id is 0 then it means check the one before where valid is 1

..If the Last entry of valid for an ID is null,then its good for nothing

Now what i am trying to do is

1. Get those IDs where the last entry for that ID got 1 as valid value
2. If the valid value of the last entry for an id is 0 then it will take the entry before that where valid is 1.
3. If the 'valid' of the last entry for an id is 0 but the value above that is null, then that id is completely avoided in result

No this is the result i am trying to acheive

[image]

So how to get this done.

How to write sql for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Nick mysql version 5.5.40

Answer (score 0):

I think you can handle this with a brute-force approach.  That is get the `no` and `valid` information from the last two rows and use that in a `where` clause:

```
select id, no, valid
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.no
              from t t2
              where t2.id = t.id
              order by t2.no desc
              limit 1
             ) as last_no,
             (select t2.valid
              from t t2
              where t2.id = t.id
              order by t2.no desc
              limit 1
             ) as last_valid,
             (select t2.no
              from t t2
              where t2.id = t.id
              order by t2.no desc
              limit 1, 1
             ) as last_no_2,    
             (select t2.valid
              from t t2
              where t2.id = t.id
              order by t2.no desc
              limit 1, 1
             ) as last_valid_2      
      from t
     ) t
where (last_valid = 1 and no = last_no) or
      (last_valid = 0 and last_valid_2 = 1 and no = last_no_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Future version of MySQL](https://modern-sql.com/blog/2018-04/mysql-8.0) will have lateral join

<strike>Here's for the future.</strike> The future is already here, I run the query below on MySQLWorkbench, with MySQL version 8.0.15, lateral join works.

The live test is for Postgres though. MySQL 8.0.15 is not yet available on db-fiddle.com, it's version 8.0.12 only.

Live test: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jQwSuyJ8Vwr3inaty6XVk7/1

```
with lr as -- gets last row of each id
(
    select  tbl.*
    from (select id, max(no) as max_no from tbl group by id) as ln 
    join tbl on (ln.id,ln.max_no) = (tbl.id,tbl.no) 
)
select x.*
from lr
cross join lateral
(
    select tbl.*
    from tbl 
    where
        -- valid = 1, good:
        lr.valid = 1 and tbl.no = lr.no

        -- valid = 0, check the one before it:
        or lr.valid = 0 and tbl.id = lr.id and tbl.no < lr.no

        -- optional. since it doesn't match anything here, no rows matched:
        --     or lr.valid is null and 1 = 0            
    order by tbl.no desc
    limit 1
) as x
where x.valid is not null
order by x.id;
```

Output:

```
| no  | id  | valid |
| --- | --- | ----- |
| 1   | 1   | 1     |
| 5   | 2   | 1     |
| 10  | 4   | 1     |
| 16  | 6   | 1     |
```

MySQL 8.0.15 is available on dbfiddle.uk: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=95a873135d22bcfce3e59839d283e9a0

---

Postgres can be made shorter by using `DISTINCT ON` instead of joining to the max(no):

Live test: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jQwSuyJ8Vwr3inaty6XVk7/2

```
with lr as -- gets last row of each id
(
    select distinct on (id) 
        *
    from tbl
    order by id, no desc
)
```